# RewriteRule in .htaccess so that it returns 410 (Gone)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I previously ran a website within another framework and some pages have been indexed with urls like `?p=773`. I want to get rid of them and here's what I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(\?p=773)$ - [G,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*p=.*)$ - [G,L]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the path component of the URL only. If you want to check on query string contents, you need to use a RewriteCond.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments you cannot match the query string of a requested URL using a `RewriteRule`. You need to use a `RewriteCond` for that. That is clearly stated in the documetation of the rewriting module. And shown in literally hundreds of existing examples here on SO.

This would be an example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:^|&)p=773(?:&|$)$
RewriteRule ^/?some/requested/path  - [G,L]
```